# HELP: cannot log into wordpress. PHP error

Tags: php, errors

I logged in to do some updates and received an error message about PHP. There has been a critical error on your website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.

Answer (score 0):

When you get that polite 'white screen of death', you'll find the problem in the error.log file in the root of your site (perhaps in the error.log file in wp-admin, if the error was caused by an admin-level program).

You can renamed the plugins folder to temporarily disable all plugins. But the error.log file will tell you exactly where the error was caused. If in a plugin, rename that plugin's folder (in the plugins folder) to temporarily disable it. Then you can proceed from there.

You might get a message in the email of the site owner (as defined on the Admin, Settings screen), but it's faster just to look at the error.log file.